# How to fix this Access-Control-Allow-Headers error

Tags: angularjs, post

I'm using angularJS for POST from localhost to some API. but I got this error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "...API link..." Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I can post to the API when I use "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" chrome extension. But this is just temporary, This way only works when I use this extension on my borwser. But my users got this problem when they use in their own browser.

How to fix this from client side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix this issue client side. The API server controls who can access what (using the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin header) so you have to change it there.

Answer (score 0):

The `CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)` Request should be enabled in your server i mean in your api like `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
, otherwise if you  still want to access the request from another domain (localhost) if api host is different ,  in your js code try to use `jsonp`

here is the documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp